# Visual Studio Code: Check semicolon on javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, lint

I need an extension for checking, if my javascript has a semicolon on the lineend. By searching the extension i only could find auto set semicolon extension, but i want to check large existing code.

Maybe i can build a custom rule?

Answer (score 20):

As Alexis Mateo mentioned you can use the [ESLint Extension for vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint).
If you want to check for semicolons after a statement you **do not** need to write your own rule.
Instead by [setting an option](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint#settings-options) like this in vscode's `settings.json`:

```
{
    "eslint.options": { "configFile": "C:/mydirectory/.eslintrc.json" }
}
```

you tell the extension where to look for the rule set it should apply.
Now you add the [semi rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi) to your `.eslintrc.json` like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "semi": ["error", "always"]
    }
}
```

[Here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) you can explore further rules.

Answer (score 3):

you need to install a extension i recommend you install esLint. esLint let you write rules to follow in your code.